# How should I add more messages to send

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Based on the example from boost https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp.
Implements a client that connects to the server and sends data.
I don't know how he should implement adding more messages sent to serer from e.g. data buffer e.g. vector etc.
E.g. Should the server after receiving the data send a "flag" message back or does it have a client for subsequent messages.Should the do_write function put the data allocation into the data_ variable?

```
void do_write(std::size_t length)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read(); // Wait For Flag Server || Client Or Allocate New Message in buffor
          }
        });
  }
```

I'm wondering if, after the flag is sent, it can happen that the data receiving session is closed before any more data is sent.
I apologize for my English.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the question is. It could be about message framing
(see e.g.  https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp18/cse291-c/post/schedule/02-Protocols.pdf)
*or* it could be about [scatter/gather](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffers_and_scatter_gather_i_o)
**or** it could be about queuing writes. You can find good examples of all the
...

Comment: ... above if you search [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe)
for any of those keywords. For queuing examples I usually call the queue
    [`outbox_`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20outbox_&searchOn=3),
    and invariably use a [`deque` to store it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20deque%20asio&searchOn=3)